# I have a fairly large SQL query that is being slowed by the GROUP BY and ORDER BY statements. What is the best way to optimize?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization, large-query

What is the best way to optimize this query as its taking up to 12 second to execute?

Apologies for the size of the query, it executes almost instantly without the group by and order by statements.

I'm fairly new to SQL optimization, I've only been coding for around a year. I didn't write this query but I need to fix it.

```
SELECT
`products`.*,
`product_alternative`.`alternative_product_code`,
`product_alternative`.`id` as `product_alternative_id`,
`vat_rate`.`rate` AS `vat_rate`,
`product_images`.`filename` AS `product_image_file`,
`product_docs`.`filename` AS `product_doc_file`,
`suppliers`.`supplier_code`,
`suppliers`.`name` AS `supplier_name`,
`commission`.`commission` AS `supplier_commission`,
`categories`.`name` AS `category_name`,
`sub_categories`.`name` AS `subcategory_name`,
IF(`products`.`product_doc_id` = 0,
 NULL,
 CONCAT(
"/product-docs/",
`products`.`id`
)) AS `product_doc_url`,IF(`products`.`product_image_id` = 0, NULL, CONCAT(
"/product-images/",
`products`.`id`,
"/original/"
)) AS `original_image_url`,IF(`products`.`product_image_id` = 0, NULL, CONCAT(
"/product-images/",
`products`.`id`,
"/medium/"
)) AS `medium_image_url`,IF(`products`.`product_image_id` = 0, NULL, CONCAT(
"/product-images/",
`products`.`id`,
"/thumb/"
)) AS `thumb_image_url`,CASE
WHEN
    `group_favourite`.`id` IS NOT NULL
    THEN 1 ELSE 0
END
AS `group_favourite`
,CASE
WHEN
    `product_favourite`.`org_id` != 0
    AND `product_favourite`.`org_id` IS NOT NULL
    THEN 1 ELSE 0
END
AS `favourite`
,CASE
WHEN
    `product_favourite`.`org_id` != 0
    AND `product_favourite`.`org_id` IS NOT NULL
    THEN 1 ELSE 0
END
AS `favourite`,
`product_favourite`.`needs_authorisation`,

 IF(`customer_personal_favourite`.`id` IS NOT NULL,1,0) AS `is_personal_favourite`
 FROM
`products` 

LEFT JOIN `vat_rate` ON `products`.`vat_rate_id` = `vat_rate`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `product_images` ON `products`.`product_image_id` = `product_images`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `product_docs` ON `products`.`product_doc_id` = `product_docs`.`id`

LEFT JOIN `orgs` AS `suppliers` ON `products`.`supplier_id` = `suppliers`.`id`

LEFT JOIN `commission` ON
    `suppliers`.`id` = `commission`.`org_id`
    AND `commission`.`status` = 1
    AND DATE(`commission`.`start_date`) <= DATE('2020-07-15')
    AND (
        DATE(`commission`.`end_date`) >= DATE('2020-07-15')
        OR `commission`.`end_date` = '0000-00-00'
    )

LEFT JOIN `categories` AS `categories` ON
    `products`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id`


LEFT JOIN `categories` AS `sub_categories` ON
    `products`.`sub_category_id` = `sub_categories`.`id`

LEFT JOIN `product_attribute_product` ON
    `product_attribute_product`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `product_alternative` ON
    `product_alternative`.`product_original_id` = `products`.`original_id`
JOIN `orgs` AS `customer` ON
`customer`.`id` IN (320)

LEFT JOIN `product_supplier_account` ON
`product_supplier_account`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`

JOIN `supplier_account` AS `default_supplier_account` ON
`default_supplier_account`.`supplier_id` = `products`.`supplier_id`
AND `default_supplier_account`.`is_default` = 1
AND `default_supplier_account`.`is_deleted` = 0

JOIN `customer_to_supplier` ON
`customer_to_supplier`.`supplier_id` = `products`.`supplier_id`
AND `customer_to_supplier`.`customer_id` IN (`customer`.`id`)
AND `customer_to_supplier`.`allow_access` = 1
AND `customer_to_supplier`.`status` = 1

JOIN `customer_to_supplier_account` ON
    `customer_to_supplier_account`.`customer_to_supplier_id` = `customer_to_supplier`.`id`
    AND (
        `customer_to_supplier_account`.`supplier_account_id` =                                    `product_supplier_account`.`supplier_account_id`
        OR `customer_to_supplier_account`.`supplier_account_id` = `default_supplier_account`.`id`
    )
    AND `customer_to_supplier_account`.`allow_access` = 1
    AND `customer_to_supplier_account`.`is_deleted` = 0
LEFT JOIN `statement_products_categories` ON
`statement_products_categories`.`product_id` = `products`.`original_id`
LEFT JOIN `product_favourite` ON
    `product_favourite`.`product_id` = `products`.`original_id`
    AND `product_favourite`.`org_id` IN (`customer`.`id`)
    LEFT JOIN `group_favourite` AS `group_favourite` ON
`products`.`original_id` = `group_favourite`.`product_id`
AND `group_favourite`.`group_id` IN (37)
LEFT JOIN `budget` AS `category_budget` ON
    `category_budget`.`org_id` IN (`customer`.`id`)
    AND `category_budget`.`budget_type_id` = 1
    AND `category_budget`.`category_id` = `products`.`category_id`
    AND
        `category_budget`.`start_date` <= CURDATE()
        AND (
            `category_budget`.`final_date` >= CURDATE()
            OR `category_budget`.`final_date` IS NULL
        )
LEFT JOIN `budget` AS `supplier_budget` ON
    `supplier_budget`.`org_id` IN (`customer`.`id`)
    AND `supplier_budget`.`budget_type_id` = 3
    AND `supplier_budget`.`supplier_id` = `products`.`supplier_id`
    AND
        `supplier_budget`.`start_date` <= CURDATE()
        AND (
            `supplier_budget`.`final_date` >= CURDATE()
            OR `supplier_budget`.`final_date` IS NULL
        )
LEFT JOIN `budget` AS `product_budget` ON
    `product_budget`.`org_id` IN (`customer`.`id`)
    AND `product_budget`.`budget_type_id` = 2
    AND
        `product_budget`.`start_date` <= CURDATE()
        AND (
            `product_budget`.`final_date` >= CURDATE()
            OR `product_budget`.`final_date` IS NULL
        )
LEFT  JOIN `customer_personal_favourite` ON
`customer_personal_favourite`.`org_id` = `customer`.`id`
AND `customer_personal_favourite`.`product_original_id` = `products`.`original_id`

WHERE
0 OR (1  AND `products`.`status` = 1  AND ((
    `products`.`parent_id` = 0
    OR `products`.`parent_id` IS NULL
)   OR (
    `product_favourite`.`org_id` IS NOT NULL
    AND `product_favourite`.`org_id` != 0
)  )  AND `products`.`id` = `products`.`current_id` )
GROUP BY `products`.`id`
ORDER BY
`favourite` DESC,

`active_date` ASC,
    `products`.`code` ASC,
    `products`.`name` ASC,
    `products`.`parent_id` ASC

 LIMIT 0, 20
```

Comment: If you know for sure that the it's slow because of GROUP BY and ORDER BY, you should add an index, which includes all order by columns. `products`.`id` should already have an index, if it's primary key.

Comment: That query is invalid anyway, and will raise an exception with newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode.)

Comment: did you check without order by?

Comment: There are various things you can do to optimize your query.
1. Never use a **SELECT * **. Always select the only columns you need.
2. Whatever column(s) you use in your WHERE clause, always add **index** to it. Indexing makes the queries really fast.
3) Instead of writing this query in the code (whatever framework you use). Make a Database View or Stored Procedure. They reduce query time very well.

Comment: @AnkitSingh - A VIEW is just syntactic sugar; it does not provide any performance benefit.  In some cases, it makes things worse.

Comment: @Eugene - A mixture of DESC and ASC makes indexing the `ORDER BY` useless unless you have 8.0.  Even then, the Optimizer may not use the index.

Answer (score 0):

I had once faced this issue and I decided at that time to write an article on this and I have compiled from different sources and optimized my query if someone wishes to see how I achieved it. Please have a look at this. https://junaidtechblog.wordpress.com/2019/09/04/optimize-sql-query-groupby-having/

Answer (score 0):

```
      AND  DATE(`commission`.`start_date`) <= DATE('2020-07-15')
      AND  ( DATE(`commission`.`end_date`) >= DATE('2020-07-15')
              OR  `commission`.`end_date` = '0000-00-00'
```

has several problems:

- `OR` is hard to optimize.  Find some way to avoid it -- such as by removing such rows, or using an end date that is far in the future, not past.
- Don't hide a column in a function call.
- Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.
- You don't need `DATE()` around the literal '2020-07-15'.

This, on the other hand, is OK:  `product_budget`.`start_date` <= CURDATE()

```
ORDER BY `favourite` DESC,
         `active_date` ASC,
```

Unless you have MySQL 8.0, no index can handle an `ORDER BY` that mixes DESC and ASC.  (It may not be possible to use an index *for other reasons*.)

```
WHERE 0 OR (1  AND ...
```

Dynamically build the query, rather than using kludges like these.

```
LEFT JOIN ... ON ... foo = 1
```

`ON` should state how the tables are related.  `foo = 1` feels more like something that should be in the `WHERE` clause (for filtering).  Moving that between `ON` and `WHERE` will *probably* change the set of rows produced.  But I am questioning whether that should be `JOIN` (instead of `LEFT JOIN`) or the test should be in `WHERE`, or whether it is actually valid the way you wrote it.

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`  The lines with the largest "rows" are likely to be the tables to focus on.

```
GROUP BY  `products`.`id`
```

is likely to lead to mangled output.  Read about "only_full_group_by".

That leads to a potential speedup.

1. Do the *minimal* amount of work to get a list of `id` to satisfy the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.
2. *Then* `JOIN` to all the other tables, including back to `products`, to get the other columns.  This is likely to speed things up *and* get rid of the above bug.
3. Where practical change `LEFT JOIN` into a subquery:

   ```
    SELECT ...
        `vat_rate`.`rate` AS `vat_rate`,
        ...
    LEFT JOIN  `vat_rate`  ON `products`.`vat_rate_id` = `vat_rate`.`id`
    ...
   ```

-->

```
    SELECT ...
        ( SELECT `rate` FROM vat_rate WHERE id = `products`.`vat_rate_id`
        )  AS `vat_rate`,
        ...
    ...
```

Get most of that done, then come back for more suggestions.